# Access code for steam

Tags: steam

I just got a new computer but forgot the access code so I can log in on this  computer. Is there any way i can change it or log in? https://support.steampowered.com/index.php

Comment: Do you mean your SteamGuard access code? You can always request for a new one to be sent to your email if the original expired.

Answer (score 2):

Try to sign into Steam. When you are asked to enter your Steam Guard code, there is an option to send you another code. Click that and check your email.

If you have forgotten the email you use for Steam or have lost access to it, you'll need to contact Steam Support.